# Error code 126/127 when using mallet on Google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, gensim, lda, mallet

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet
# mallet_path = 'C:/Users/kmuth/Downloads/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet' # update this path
mallet_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet'
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=doc_term_matrix, num_topics=15, id2word=dictionary)
```

I'm currently having this error:
CalledProcessError: Command '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input /tmp/d20b66_corpus.txt --output /tmp/d20b66_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 126.

when trying to create an lda model using mallet as i have read it somehow does a better job than the built in lda model in the gensim package.

i'm trying to follow this tutorial(to try the mallet bit):
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/#14computemodelperplexityandcoherencescore

I would really appreciate any help as I don't have any idea to what the error is. Is it not finding the file, do I have to install it? Pretty much a noob

I have tried to change the mallet path around from my pc and from my drive with no avail.

Thank you, Sean

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, Google Colab runs on Google's servers.

Did you compile/install the native `mallet` executable (on which that `gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet` depends) to a path and format – accessable to the notebook – from which the Google Colab notebook can execute it? (Is that even allowed in Google Colab?)

Note also that the latest (4.0+) versions of Gensim have eliminated the `wrappers` as somewhat awkward to use, hard-to-maintain, & somewhat redundant with other implementations. So you may want to consider using Gensim's own `LdaModel` instead of this no-longer-supported wrapper of another package.

Comment: I did not, I just downloaded the mallet file and followed the instructions...

Comment: Generally such native executables need to be specific to the machine where they will run. There's little chance a compiled `mallet` command that works on a x86 Windows machine will work on whatever (probably Linux-like) system Google is running, even *if* Google Colab lets you upload arbitrary executables.

Comment: Also, I've never heard of this site `machinelearningplus.com`, so the idea of downloading a ZIP from it & blindly running code inside could be reckless, from the perspective of keeping whatever system, or data, you are running it on secure. (It is much better to get libraries/packages from the authentic original authors, or official/well-maintained package repositories.